# Stretching the items of a grouped ListView horizontally

Tags: listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

[image: Screenshot of my app]

I'd like to stretch the items of my listview horizontally, so that the green area (a selected ItemContainer) reaches from the groupheader to the right.

I've tried to set every element i could think of to "HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"" but nothing worked.

Here is my ListView

```
<ListView
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            x:Name="AppointmentListView"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SelectedViewSource}}"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="200">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateYearStringConv}, Path=Key}" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Margin="10, 5, 0, 0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem" >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="400" Height="60" Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock Text="Here goes the content" />
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

ItemContainerStyle

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Thickness>0</Thickness>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" To="NoSelectionHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                    <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF82BA00"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF82BA00"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF82BA00"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill)" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF82BA00"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                    <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                    <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent">
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                            <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Margin="0" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,9,0,0" Opacity="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution!

I had to change the GroupItemTemplate inside the GroupStyle.ContainerStyle to a Grid

```
<GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="GroupItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupItems}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Also didn't work for me (Windows Phone 8.1 Store App)

Answer (score 4):

This is what's needed for the header:

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `ItemContainerStyle` (*AppointmentListView*) set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`

Comment: That sadly doesn't work, the green area that you can see in the screenshot is a selected ItemContainer, not an ItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alexandre Zollinger Chohfi's answer, a more concise version:

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
```